# ¿por qué javascipt me dice que Viaje1.simularcosto no es una function?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Comunidad, los saludo. Estaba pasando un objeto hecho con function constructor a class, pero no entiendo por qué no me toma la funcion simularCosto sino que me parece un mensaje en la consola de que supuestamente Viaje_1.simularcosto() no es un función. Cuando estaba en función constructora todo funcionaba perfecto y ahora que quiero transformar ese objeto a class, ya no funcionó más, de hecho la función display es la única que funciona. Si alguien me puede ayudar, le agradezco.

```
class Viaje {
        constructor(destino, valor, duracion) {
            this.destino = destino;
            this.valor = parseFloat(valor);
            this.duracion = parseInt(duracion);
        }
        
        display(){ 
            console.log("Has seleccionado " + this.destino + " para una duracion de " + this.duracion + " por valor de " + this.valor);
        }
        
        simularCosto(){ 
            console.log("El costo aproximado será de: " + (this.valor * 1.35));
        }
    }
    
    const Viaje_1 = new Viaje("Paris", "450.7", "15");
    const Viaje_2 = new Viaje("Berlin", "516.30", "8");
    
    Viaje_1.display();
    Viaje_1.simularcosto();
    
    Viaje_2.display();
    Viaje_2.simularcosto();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la clase declaras:

```
simularCosto(){}
```

Y luego llamas a

```
Viaje_1.simularcosto();
```

La c es mayúscula en la declaración, por lo que simularcosto con c minúscula no existe.